# i am unable to use GPU in tensorflow whereas theano works fine

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

am working on linux(ubuntu 16.04) and my laptop has nvidia geforce 840m. I have tried installing tensorflow GPU by following the steps on their site and also CUDA and cuDNN. But somehow while running the code on spyder IDE and then checking out nvidia status using nvidia-smi it says there are no process running on GPU. i am not able to fix this. please help if anyone was able to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

i have these environments in my conda:

```
$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
tensorflow               /home/vaibhav/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow

root                  *  /home/vaibhav/anaconda3`
```

Also when i import keras using theanos it says following:

```
import keras
Using Theano backend.
WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): The cuda backend is deprecated and will be removed in the next release (v0.10).  Please switch to the gpuarray backend. You can get more information about how to switch at this URL:
 https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Converting-to-the-new-gpu-back-end%28gpuarray%29

Using gpu device 0: GeForce 840M (CNMeM is enabled with initial size: 75.0% of memory, cuDNN 5110)`
```

When using theanos backend the nvidia-smi shows anaconda using nvidia gpu0.
thus i have all the prerequisites installed successfully

Comment: Did you install the tensorflow-gpu version?

Comment: yes after intalling tensorflow i used this command after activating tensorflow to install gpu version:  `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.2.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl`

Comment: just try without using tensorflow as keras backend and use tf directly(some example codes from github), see what happens.